# SecAddItem Only Retuns errSecParam, No Matter I Do

Tags: ios, ios7, keychain, security-framework

For some reason I can't get this simple keychain code to work.

```
//Let's create an empty mutable dictionary:
NSMutableDictionary *keychainItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSString *username = self.nwUsernameTxtFld.text;
NSString *password = self.passwordTxtFld.text;

//Populate it with the data and the attributes we want to use.

keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecClass] = (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword; // We specify what kind of keychain item this is.
keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible] = (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked; // This item can only be accessed when the user unlocks the device.
keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrServer] = @"http://www.myawesomeservice.com";
keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount] = username; //Our username.

if(SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainItem, NULL) == noErr)
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"The Item Already Exists", nil)
                                                    message:NSLocalizedString(@"Please update it instead.", )
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}else
{
    NSLog(@"can add new item.");
    keychainItem[(__bridge id)kSecValueData] = password; //Our password

    OSStatus sts = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainItem, NULL);
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)sts);
}
```

I have checked Apple's documentation on the matter and according to it:

> One or more parameters passed to the function were not valid.

Yet, the `SecAddItem` function takes two paramters:

```
OSStatus SecItemAdd (
   CFDictionaryRef attributes,
   CFTypeRef *result
);
```

I am passing NULL to result. This is acceptable according to Apple's documentation:

> result On return, a reference to the newly added items. The exact type
>   of the result is based on the values supplied in attributes, as
>   discussed below. Pass NULL if this result is not required.

So I Don't really know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm passing it a dictionary and a NULL value. The function expects both and I'm giving it both. Can someone please enlighten me as to what's wrong?

For reference, the documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemAdd).

Comment: What is the type of `password` in this code?

Comment: NSString. Both username and password are NSString.

Comment: And what is the type listed for `kSecValueData` at the bottom of the page that you linked?

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I let that error pass. Feel free to add your comments as a more elaborated answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are inserting an incorrect data type into the dictionary for the key `kSecValueData`.  As indicated in the documentation at the bottom of your question, it needs to be `CFDataRef` (or bridged `NSData`) but you are inserting an `NSString` instead.  It is a trivial matter to convert `NSString` to `NSData` and once you do so you will stop having this error.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error for setting the wrong kSecClass. I had used kSecClassInternetPassword instead of kSecClassGenericPassword. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please justify why. At least to me, it makes sense this could be another cause for that error.

Comment: As conveyed, I did get this error for this reason , so down voter kindly justify why you feel otherwise